# Create a 5x5 Modulo Grid

Tags: number-theory

Create a 5x5 grid.

```
A1 A2 a3 a4 a5

B1 B2 b3 b4 b5

c1 c2 c3 c4 c5

d1 d2 d3 d4 d5

e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
```

Seed A1, A2, B1 and B2 with numbers that allow the grid to be completed with following criteria:

- Except in the first to columns, every cell must be the modulo of the 2 cells left to it.
- Except in the first two rows, every cell must be the modulo of the 2 cells above it.
- No more than one cell is allowed to be 0.
- Numbers may repeat in the grid

I.e.

- c3 = a3%b3 = c1%c2
- e5 = e3%e4 = c5%d5
- ...

The solution with the lowest sum of initial numbers wins.

**Bonus Question:**

Can you choose 4 different numbers to start with? (That adds a hell of complexity :)

Comment: `b5 = b3 % b4`, but how does it work vertically for b5?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated description for better clarity.

Comment: Is there an implicit requirement that the numbers are non-negative?  I guess it depends on how you define modulo with negative numbers, but bc at least tells me -5 % -8 is -5 (and not say 3)

Answer (score 6):

Based on Jamal Senjaya answer:
Sum is 34

> ```
>  [ 5  8  5  3  2]
>  [ 8 13  8  5  3]
>  [ 5  8  5  3  2]
>  [ 3  5  3  2  1]
>  [ 2  3  2  1  0]
> ```

You can create other solutions by using other Fibonacci numbers as start. For example:

> ```
>  [ 8 13  8  5  3]
>  [13 21 13  8  5]
>  [ 8 13  8  5  3]
>  [ 5  8  5  3  2]
>  [ 3  5  3  2  1]
> ```

Comment: I honestly can't think of a better solution, so this might be the winner. Could you apply that approach to the bonus question, so we have everything in one place?

Answer (score 3):

For the standard question we can

> just start with `0` in the bottom right, with `1` above and to it's left and add - this forms diagonals of Fibonacci numbers:
>
> ```
>    34   21   13    8    5
>
>
>    21   13    8    5    3
>
>
>    13    8    5    3    2
>
>
>     8    5    3    2    1
>
>
>     5    3    2    1    0
> ```

This should be minimal sum, for $192$

---

For the bonus we can

> change one of the bottom or right `2`s to a `3` and sum again, here is changing the bottom one:
>
> ```
>    50   29   21    8    5
>
>
>    31   18   13    5    3
>
>
>    19   11    8    3    2
>
>
>    12    7    5    2    1
>
>
>     7    4    3    1    0
> ```

As pointed out by @wl another way to construct the bonus (and almost certainly with minimal score) is to

> shift the left-most column, or top most row, of the first solution up the Fibonacci scale by one place:
>
> ```
>    55   21   13    8    5
>
>
>    34   13    8    5    3
>
>
>    21    8    5    3    2
>
>
>    13    5    3    2    1
>
>
>     8    3    2    1    0
> ```

For $242$ instead of the previous $268$

Comment: For the bonus question just replace each number in the first column or row with the next highest Fibonacci number: 55, 34, 21, 13, 8

Comment: @wl Ah yes that will make minimum bonus I think - I just did it another way (but for more cost)

Answer (score 3):

Sum is 55

> ```
>  [8  13  8  5  3]
>  [13 21  13 8  5]
>  [8  13  8  5  3]
>  [5   8  5  3  2]
>  [3   5  3  2  1]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

One solution but it may not be optimal:

> ```
>  34 21 13  8  5
>
>  21 13  8  5  3
>
>  13  8  5  3  2
>
>   8  5  3  2  1
>
>   5  3  2  1  0
> ```

.

> Started with 0 and 1 in the bottom right corner and moved my way up.  (notice the symmetry).